# default text change into input text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple form with three input text with a different value for each.
I want when I click inside at one to clear the deafult value and when I go out to put the default text into the input if the user doesn't insert a text.
I have write a code in jQuery the problem is when I click out it takes the same default value of the first input type and not its text why?
This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.testo').each(function() {
    var default_value = this.value;
        $(".testo").focus(function() {
            $(this).attr('value','');
        });
        $(".testo").blur(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('value')==''){
                $(this).attr('value',default_value);
            }
        });
    });
});

<p><input type="text" name="nome" class="testo"  value="Nome e Cognome"/> </p>
            <p><input type="text" name="telefono" class="testo" value="un tuo Recapito Telefonico"/></p>
            <p><input type="text" name="email"  class="testo" maxlength="60" value="una E-Mail Valida"/></p>
```

Comment: validate entered text with default text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your javascript isn't using the same value each time you bind the focus and blur events. so these will always bind to the last in the each, try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.testo').each(function() {
    var default_value = this.value;
        $(this).focus(function() {
            $(this).val('');
        });
        $(this).blur(function() {
            if ($(this).val()==''){
                $(this).val(default_value);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `attr('value')` should be `.val()`

Answer (score 5):

You could achieve this without javascript, using the placeholder attribute of the input:

```
<input type="text" name="telefono" class="testo" placeholder="un tuo Recapito Telefonico"/>
```

Find an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MNWxE/)

EDIT:

Have in account that this is html5 and, although [it's quite widely supported by browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder), if you want to support them all, you should follow @liam's approach.

Comment: Bear in mind this is HTML5 so you'll need to be careful with compatibility with old browsers

Answer (score 0):

***[The working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5mCFt/)***.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.testo').each(function() {
        var default_value = this.value;
        // you could do chain method to avoid call $(this) twice.
        $(this).focus(function() {
            $(this).val('');
        }).blur(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == ''){
                $(this).val(default_value);
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Is it me or have you just cut and pasted my code into an answer?

Comment: @Liam It's just duplicated, and i will delete this answer. No need to copy your code :)

Comment: @Liam Oh, I think i should leave the answer because your answer do `$(this)` twice.